# Importing UDP Multicast signal into Python

Tags: python, arrays, struct, udp, multicast

I'm currently trying to import a UDP Multicast signal (an EEG signal) into Python. Although I do get a signal, the output consists of an array of letters, numbers, and symbols which can't be displayed properly, so something is not quite right.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '234.5.6.7'
MCAST_PORT = 58432

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)

sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
print sock.recv(51)
```

Now, the last line (print sock.recv(51)) seems to instruct Python to output the contents of the receive buffer as an ASCII string. I was told that I have to convert the buffer data to a byte array and then get the elements from the array that I need.
Say for instance I have an array of 51 elements and I want to know what the voltage is on channel 5, I would then get elements 18 (high byte) and 19 (low byte) from the array and convert them to a short integer (16 bit value).
I was told that I can can use Python's struct.unpack function for this: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/struct.html.

I only have basic Python programming skills myself, so all of this is new territory for me. After reading the documentation, it seems to me as if the struct.unpack function needs two arguments. The first specifies the way in which the data was packed up in the first place. In my case, this is "4sl"; I'm writing four characters followed by a long integer to a byte vector. The second argument has to state what data has to be unpacked. Using struct.unpack("4sl", sock.recv(51) returns the error message that "unpack requires a string argument of length 8", however. This makes sense as sock.recv(51) just gives me the live contents of the receive buffer which far exceeds that length. I must admit that I'm at a bit of a loss. I'd be really thankful if anybody could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have python 2.7 recv will return a byte array

each character is a byte

to change them into 51 ints you would simply map to int

```
bytestring = sock.recv(51)
[int(ch) for ch in bytestring]
```

you could unpack bytes more smartly with struct

```
struct.unpack_from("bbb",bytestring)
```

would unpack 3 bytes

```
struct.unpack_from("Hh",bytstring)
```

would unpack an unsigned short and then a signed short from bytestring
and so on

Comment: Thank you very much! The signal I`m working with sends packets that each contain 51 bytes. I assume that using the following code gives me the unpacked packets:
bytestring = sock.recv(51)
signal = struct.unpack_from ("b"*51, bytestring)
print signal

Thanks again for your help!